# Pass data from CollectionView Delegate to another ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

I'm beginner on Swift.

I have `CollectionView` in my `UIViewController` and I need to pass data when user clicks on `CollectionViewCell` to another `ViewController`.
I tried to override `prepareForSegue` but I notice that it called first then code on `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`.

**My First ViewController Code:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    ...

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

extension ViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate{

    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("collCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MainCollectionViewCell

        ...
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        itemId = items[indexPath.item].id

        let distinationViewController = DistinationViewController()
        distinationViewController.itemId = itemId
    }   
}
```

**My Distination view controller code**

```
import UIKit

class DistinationViewController: UIViewController{

    var itemId : String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        print(itemId)
    }
}
```

The value of `itemId` in `DistinationViewController` is nil

Thanks

Comment: You have a segue set up from collectionview cell?

Comment: @Keviv yes, i have

Comment: Okay, you need to do 2 things. 1. Connect your segue from the ViewController and not from cell. 2. Call `performSegueWithIdentifier` in `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath` and fetch destination view controller there and assign itemID there.

Comment: ok, but i have 3 collectionviews in the same view controller, how can i identify which one starts the segue

Comment: Please see my answer,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. Change your `func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
   didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` to the following
   one:

   ```
       func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

           // Here you can check which Collection View is triggering the segue
           if collectionView == collectionView1 {
               self.performSegueWithIdentifier("fromFirstCollectionView", sender: nil);
           } else if collectionView == collectionView2 {
               // from other CollectionView
           }
       }
   ```

   and your `prepareForSegue` method will be like this

   ```
   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

           // Even here you can check for segue.identifiers if you have something to differentiate
           let dvc = segue.destinationViewController as! DestinationViewController
           dvc.itemId = "Hello"
       }
   ```
2. Connect `segue` from your View Controller and assign it an `identifier`

According to your comment you have 3 `collectionView` so i guess you need 3 segues with 3 different identifiers.

Hope this helps! Happy to discuss if you have more questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to change the view through code like :

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        itemId = items[indexPath.item].id
        let distinationViewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DestinationViewControllerStoryBoardID") as! DistinationViewController

        distinationViewController.itemId = itemId
self.navigationController.pushViewController(distinationViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: that's work for me. but is it correct to let main storyboard controllers without segue?

Answer (score 0):

You can put everything in your prepareForSegue. Like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let identifier = segue.identifier{
        switch identifier {
            case "distinationViewController":
                if let nextScene =  segue.destinationViewController as? DistinationViewController {
                    if let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems.lastItem {
                        nextScene.itemId=items[indexPath.item].id
                        nextScene.delegate = self
                }
            }
            default: break
        }
    }
}
```